# Equals behavior issue in a Grails closure

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

$ grails -v
| Grails Version: 3.3.9

### | JVM Version: 1.8.0_161

I wrote a util class under 'src/' folder, not under grails-app.

```
    def getSelectedColumnCfgs() {
        def cfgs = cfgFile.readLines().findAll { it.startsWith('COLUMN:') }.collect { line ->
            line[7..-1].trim().split(',').collectEntries {
                it.trim().split('=').collect { it.trim() }
            }
        } // We get a List<Map<String, String>>

        cfgs.each { cfg ->
            def column = nsTable.columns.find {
                it.name == cfg.ns_columm //equals condition behave weird
            }
            //something else
        }
    }
```

In normal case, the find closure will return a column object which its name equals to cfg.ns_columm (a map), but it doesn't. So I tried following comparism:

```
//Doesn't work
columns.find {
    println it.name == cfg.ns_column //it dose print a 'true' when they matched
    it.name == cfg.ns_column
}


//Works! But why?
columns.find {
    boolean flag = it.name == cfg.ns_column
    flag
}
```

I guess in some cases, the find function will be overridden by GORM, but this code is not under grails-app and Column is not a domain class, so, any clue?

Comment: What is the result of `println (it.name == cfg.ns_column).getClass()`

Comment: println((it.name == cfg.ns_column).getClass())
result: class java.lang.Boolean

Comment: What does it mean 'does not work'? Any error?

Comment: wonder if is the `it` try chaging the it to something unique -> `def column = nsTable.columns.find { n-> n.name == cfg.ns_columm}`

Comment: 'doesn't work' means the find closure won't return anything even when the condition is true. But when I came back to it and try to test if changing 'it' to something unique help, I found, the issue is gone. I checked local history, no other modifications. Maybe something wrong with IDEA? no idea...